# Jetpack compose DropdownMenu With rounded Corners

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-dropdownmenu

Hello I can't figure out how to make a cut corners menu in jetpack compose `1.0.0-beta02`. I tried wrapping the while menu with a surface but It didn't work.

```kotlin
    TopAppBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .statusBarsPadding(),
        title = {
            Text(text = "Title")
        },
        actions = {
            var menuExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

            IconButton(onClick = { menuExpanded = true }) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.MoreVert, contentDescription = null)
            }

            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = menuExpanded,
                onDismissRequest = {
                    menuExpanded = false
                },
            ) {
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
                    Text("Item 2")
                }
            }
        },
    )
```

**Which gives me**

[image: No Cut corners]

But I **need something like this**, which is rounded.

[image: menu with Material Theming]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using a **M2 MaterialTheme** theme, the default shape used by the `DropdownMenu` is defined by the
**`medium`** attribute in the `shapes` used in the `MaterialTheme` (check your theme).

```
val Shapes = Shapes(
    small = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
    medium = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),  //<- used by `DropdownMenu`
    large = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
)
```

You can change this value in your theme or you can override the medium shape only in your `DropdownMenu`.
Something like:

```
    MaterialTheme(shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes.copy(medium = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))) {
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = menuExpanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                menuExpanded = false
            }                
        ) {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
                Text("Item 2")
            }
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
                Text("Item 3")
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Using a **M3 MaterialTheme** the default shape used by the DropdownMenu is defined by the **`extraSmall`** attribute in the shapes:

```
MaterialTheme(
    shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes.copy(extraSmall = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))){

    //... DropdownMenu()

}
```

Comment: Note that `DropdownMenu` from `compose.material3` library uses `extraSmall` shape instead of `medium`.

Comment: How do I change the back ground color? Thanks

Comment: Change background with `Modifier.background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)` on the `DropDownMenu`.