# Round corners for Dropdown menu compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-dropdownmenu

Before, I posted here, I Googled a lot. I found the following: `MaterialTheme(shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes.copy(medium = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))){}` from the following SO post: [Jetpack compose DropdownMenu With rounded Corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66781028/jetpack-compose-dropdownmenu-with-rounded-corners)

**EDIT:** I am using Material Design v3.

---

```
  MaterialTheme(shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes.copy(medium = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))) {
            IconButton(
                            onClick = { showMenu = !showMenu }) {
                            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.MoreVert, contentDescription = "")
                            DropdownMenu(
                                expanded = showMenu,
                                onDismissRequest = { showMenu = false },
                                modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background).padding(4.dp)
                            ) {
                                DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Refresh", fontSize = 16.sp) },  onClick = { showMenu = false })
                                DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Settings", fontSize = 16.sp) },  onClick = { showMenu = false })
                                Divider(color = Color.LightGray, thickness = 1.dp)
                                DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text("Send Feedback", fontSize = 16.sp) },  onClick = { showMenu = false })
                            }
                        }
        }
```

---

**Currently it produces the following output:**

[image]

There certainly is some border radius, it isn't achieving the desired goal. The second screenshot from a third-party app, does have the border radius I am trying to get.

[image]

Comment: Note that `DropdownMenu` from compose.material3 library uses `extraSmall` shape instead of `medium`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, yes, I read this somewhere. But, can this not be modified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With material3 the default shape used by the `DropdownMenu` is defined by the **`extraSmall`** attribute in the shapes

You have to use:

```
MaterialTheme(
    shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes.copy(extraSmall = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
){

    //... DropdownMenu()

}
```

[image]